# Doesn't work examples from angularfire tutorial

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

When I try to run page as described in https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/

```
    <html ng-app="sampleApp">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.6/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.6.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="SampleController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text"/>
    <h1>You said: {{text}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and app.js:

```
 angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"])
  .factory("sampleService", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://sizzling-fire-8112.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebase(ref);
  }])
  .controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "sampleService",
    function($scope, service) {
      service.$bind($scope, "text");
    }
  ]);
```

There is: You said: {{text}} on the web screen.
What I did wron? 
Thanks ;)

Comment: and what does console output?

Comment: I didnt know how to use console :D Just it need to me for making project in the university. Grabbing some peoples from social-network, by using api, and do something, and let other groups to manipulate with something my system does. After seeking for a while I decide angularjs, but too huge "familiar" with any kind a js or sth. So I kinda zero. :D

Comment: if you're using Chrome hit F12, then go to Console tab

Comment: Wow thanks, hi cant load fro CDN. Walk to check what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are opening this page not via webserver, but directly from filesystem.
If so, **never do that way**. There can be various restrictions with AJAX, canvas, etc.

In your example you're trying to load outer scripts with [protocol relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).
In case of opening page from filesystem, URLs are being transformed into `file://...` format.

To solve this problem you should use a webserver. If you can't use it for some reasons, add `http:` to the beginning of the outer URLs, so it will be:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js
```

instead of

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js
```

Comment: Yes, it is thanks a lot! And I can't vote for you, said that need at last 15 reputations =(

Comment: you're welcome:) You can come back to this page when you get 15 reps :D